# How can I set a sample size using redis-cli --latency command?

Tags: redis, redis-cli

I'm trying to write a script to monitor the redis latency from my server. I saw about the `redis-cli --latency` command but can't find any way to preset to sample size it should actually measure, so I can actually see the difference in latency over time. I can't find documentation on this or any actual way to do this.

Is this possible and if it is, how?

Comment: maybe useful? [Understanding latency using Redis-Cli](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27735411/understanding-latency-using-redis-cli).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, atm `redis-cli`'s sample size when using the `--latency` switch isn't configurable. This mode is designed to be interactive rather than scriptable, but you are more than welcome to submit the question/challenge/idea to the forum of the mailing list (https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/redis-db).